# Cannot publish to npm from GitHub Actions: `<package> is not in the npm registry` error

Tags: npm, github-actions, npm-publish

I can successfully publish my npm package from the command line, but when I try to publish it automatically via a GitHub action, using an Automation token, I get:

```
npm notice name:          stereo-img                              
npm notice version:       0.4.0                                   
npm notice package size:  12.3 kB                                 
npm notice unpacked size: 39.7 kB                                 
npm notice shasum:        9b9cf99342b7bf2e6ff36f9fe6448a5d31ed39fb
npm notice integrity:     sha512-3vwZWK4Ndddvr[...]zr02dd0Mb9KgA==
npm notice total files:   10                                      
npm notice 
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/stereo-img - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'stereo-img@0.4.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-11-12T07_21_22_598Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

my GitHub Actions workflow is the following:

```
name: Publish package on npm

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  publish-npm:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.npm_token}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix it by ensuring I was using the `registry-url` in the `actions/setup-node@v2` step:

```
name: Publish package on npm

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  publish-npm:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.npm_token}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was facing same issues but this is really worked properly

Comment: Does not work. I both added  the registry-url and the env: NPM_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}. Really out of ideas here...